# Tikz plot drawing

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to get a drawing like this:

[image]

I was trying to put the axis in, but it does not appear on my attempt.  Please help.

**Code:**

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[axis lines=middle,
            xlabel=$x$,
            ylabel=$y$,
            enlargelimits,
            ytick=\empty]
\coordinate (A) at (2.5,4.7);
\coordinate (B) at (2.80,2.0);
\coordinate (C) at (3.75,1.50);
\coordinate (D) at (6.7,0.75);

\draw (6.7,1.00) .. controls (3,1.7) and (2.4,1.7) .. (2.5,4.7) ;
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your simple drawing, `pgfplots` seems to be an overkill. Here is a draft as plain `tikzpicture`.

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\begin{document}
\sffamily
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,>=stealth']
\draw[->] (0,-0.3) -- node[above,rotate=90]{Percentage} (0,5);
\draw[->] (-0.3,0) -- node[below]{Accuracy} (5,0);
\draw (0.3,0.3) to[out=0,in=-100] (4.5,4.5) node[left]{FRR};
\draw (0.3,4.5) node[right]{FAR} to[out=-80,in=-180] (4.5,0.3);
\node at (2.4,1.7) {\small Equilibrium};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

When compiling your document one gets the error

```
Package pgfplots Warning: You have an axis with empty range (in direction y). R
eplacing it with a default range and clearing all plots. on input line 20.
```

This is quite informative. Your diagram contains no information about the range on the x- and y-axis, so `pgfplots` assumes some defaults and ignores everything in your plot.

You can provide the information about the range either explicitly by including something like

```
xmin = 0, xmax = 7,
ymin = 0, ymax = 5,
```

in the list of options for the `axis` environment. Or you supply the information implicitly by some plot.

Here is your example with a plot and your curve; the range is determined by the plot.

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[axis lines=middle,
            xlabel=$x$,
            ylabel=$y$,
            enlargelimits,
%            xmin = 0, xmax = 7,
%            ymin = 0, ymax = 5,
            ticks=none]
\addplot[domain=0.5:6.5] {(0.25*x)^3};
\coordinate (A) at (2.5,4.7);
\coordinate (B) at (2.80,2.0);
\coordinate (C) at (3.75,1.50);
\coordinate (D) at (6.7,0.75);
\draw (6.7,1.00) .. controls (3,1.7) and (2.4,1.7) .. (2.5,4.7) ;
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

which gives the following plot.

[image]